# Webpack and Sass correctly processes background: url() image but then it's not found when used with webpack-dev-server

Tags: css, sass, webpack, sass-loader, css-loader

I am using Webpack 2 and webpack-dev-server together with Sass loader, actual configuration:

```
{
    test: /\.scss/,
    loaders: [
        "style",
        { loader: "css", query: { modules: false, sourceMap: true } },
        { loader: "resolve-url" },
        { loader: "sass", query: { sourceMap: true } }
    ]
}
```

This works quite well and the image referenced in `background: url()` is processed by webpack and also replaced in the style for something like `background-somehash.jpg`, this file can be accessed by typing `http://localhost:8080/background-somehash.jpg`. It also works when I provide whole url (including localhost) in a style background definition using developer tools...

The only thing that don't work is the original css produced by webpack which looks like `background: url(background-somehash.jpg)`. I also tried various urls like `./`, `../`, `../../` or `./images/` to try out if root was set somehow differently. What I don't get is that the file is readily available at the root...

**EDIT:** 
When used together with `extract-text-webpack-plugin` which extracts styles into separate real `styles.css` file it works just fine. The question is why it doesn't work when final css is being served from javascript bundle ?

**CLARIFICATION:** 
Everything is referenced correctly, the image is available, it all works when I extract css into separate file using `extract-text-webpack-plugin` it just doesn't work when the completely same css is served from `bundle.js` which is then referenced in the `index.html` like `<link href="blob:..." rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: What does this have to do with Sass, exactly?  Unless you're getting a different compiled CSS than you're expecting, this has nothing to do with Sass.

Comment: Well the thing is I don't know, I read some blog post that when importing sass files from other sass files the relative paths may get broken, hats also the reason why I am using source maps and `resolve-url` plugin as in example... So maybe is some sass interaction / inner working not sure...

Comment: Sass just compiles to CSS.  That's it.  If your compiled CSS contains exactly what you're expecting, then Sass has nothing to do with your problem.  Do you even *know* what you're expecting it to contain?

Answer (score 0):

Things you should check:

#### Is the referenced image recognized by webpack?

Just delete the image and check if the webpack build fails. If that's the case, it is not an issue with your loader configuration.

#### Check the requested URL with your browser developer tools

If the request is terminated with a 404:

- Check if [`output.publicPath`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-publicpath) (webpack) / [`contentBase`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#content-base) (webpack-dev-server) point to the same location. This is from the browser's perspective (=no absolute file paths)
- If you're using a [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)-tag, you need to ensure that it does replace the base URL correctly.

Comment: Answers are for *answering the question*.  If you would like to ask for clarification, use comments until you have enough information to definitively answer the question.

Comment: Everything is referenced correctly, the image is available, it all works when I extract css into separate file using `extract-text-webpack-plugin` it just doenst work when the completely same css is served from `bundle.js` which is then referenced in the `index.html` like `<link href="blob:..." rel="stylesheet">`